# I am not being able to change the state of my state objects in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am changing the state of my state object but getting the above mentioned error, even though I am not using any life cycle method. This is the error that I get:-

I am getting the error in my retainData() method.

```
×
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
 repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.
 React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

 const price = this.state.animeObject.price;
  118 |    const genre = this.state.animeObject.genre;
  119 | 
> 120 |    this.setState({
      | ^  121 |      animeName: animeName,
  122 |      animeDirector: animeDirector,
  123 |      animeStudio: animeStudio,
View compiled

131 | 
  132 |  render() {
  133 |    return (
> 134 |      <div>
      | ^  135 |        {this.prevState()}
  136 |        {this.retainData()}
  137 |        <h1> The Data going to be Edited :-</h1>
```

Below is my code  !

```
export default class EditAnimeList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animeName: "",
      animeStudio: "",
      animeDirector: "",
      rating: "",
      genre: "",
      price: "",
      animeObject: {},
    };
    this.prevState = this.prevState.bind(this); // show the data to be edited
    this.retainData = this.retainData.bind(this);
  }


  prevState(event) {
    const path = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    const id = path[path.length - 1];
    const anime = {
      id: id,
    };

    console.log("THE IDD is", id);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/anime/find", anime)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          animeObject: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }


retainData() {
    console.log("anime director is", this.state.animeObject.animeDirector);
    const animeName = this.state.animeObject.animeName;
    const animeDirector = this.state.animeObject.animeDirector;
    const animeStudio = this.state.animeObject.animeStudio;
    const rating = this.state.animeObject.rating;
    const price = this.state.animeObject.price;
    const genre = this.state.animeObject.genre;

    this.setState({
      animeName: animeName,
      animeDirector: animeDirector,
      animeStudio: animeStudio,
      rating: rating,
      price: price,
      genre: genre,
    });

    console.log("anime director is (submit )", this.state.animeDirector)
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.prevState()}
        {this.retainData()}
</div>
);

}
}
```

I only want to call the above function once. I am getting the error when I call my retainData() method and it is turning to an infinite loop.

Comment: You're setting state during render, which would cause a re-render, etc.

Comment: why are you calling those methods in render?

Comment: In general, this should never happen; you should not be doing anything remotely related to modifying any component's state within a render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animeName: "",
      animeStudio: "",
      animeDirector: "",
      rating: "",
      genre: "",
      price: "",
      animeObject: {},
    };
    this.prevState = this.prevState.bind(this); // show the data to be edited
    this.retainData = this.retainData.bind(this);
    this.prevState();

  }
 componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.retainData();
   }, 500)
  }
```

Just created a componentDidMount() with a setTimeout function ! and I was able to change state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lifecycle method componentDidMount() to load the data when component mounts and then render data on page using triggered event

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.prevState();
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <button onClick = {this.retainData}>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but this doesn't work. You cannot call a function which call setState inside your render component like this (without any trigger or condition). Here, when your function `this.retainData()`is called, the function change the state and in React when the state changes, the component rerender. So here, your function is called after each render, and because of your function set the state, React will rerender and the function will we be called again and will set the state again and React will rerender and so on.

Comment: Yes, I found my mistake. As you stated, I was rerendering my methods.

Answer (score 0):

Insert both functions - prevState, retainData into the Lifecycle method componentDidMount